# How to open the file that was searched in CMD

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I searched a file in command prompt using

```
dir /s *584.pdf
```

The file was found and the result is as follows

```
 Volume in drive Z is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is E49F-4208

 Directory of Z:\OHE_Design\DFCC\EMP-4 OHE\Submissions\References\Received\CTP-1 & 2\05-Bridge Mast files\CTP 1 & 2 DETAILS\OHE approval letters\L-NKC-SLT-PMC-1612-48

12/14/2016  05:11 PM         8,180,090 2-MB-13-011-OHE_Rev.0 584.pdf
               1 File(s)      8,180,090 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               1 File(s)      8,180,090 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  47,574,523,904 bytes free
```

Now, i want to open the file that i searched for, is there any command to do that? How shall i proceed?

Comment: Suneel, to use the `Dir` command place it inside a `For`-`In`-`Do` statement, `For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir/B/S *584.pdf 2^>Nul') Do Start ""  "%A"`. Note that the above is for the command prompt despite your batch-file tag. If you are using the command from within a batch file, then double up the **`%`** characters, `For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/S *584.pdf 2^>Nul') Do Start "" "%%A"`. Please be aware that if there are multiple files matching your search mask, `*584.pdf`, they will all be opened, _if the default application for reading `.pdf` files allows for multiple running instances_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r "Z:\OHE_Design" %%a in ("*584.pdf") do (
   start "" "%%~fa"
)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with some code and it seemed to work for me luckily.

```
@echo off
set /p search="Enter the file : "
cd "C:\users\suneel\desktop\Potato 23"
dir /s /b /a-d "*%search%*.pdf">"test.txt"
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' GOTO OPEN
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='1' echo Please search manually or Confirm with Authorities
:CONT
del "test.txt"
PAUSE
EXIT

:OPEN
set /p extract=<"test.txt"
start "" "%extract%"
echo FILE FOUND
echo Please wait while the file opens.
GOTO CONT
```

Comment: Did you not try the two examples given as both answer and comment a day earlier. It seems rude to ask, ignore both solutions and post your own without explanation. Whilst your different approach may work, it seems inefficient to each time write to a file, read and delete it, but well done nonetheless.